# fputcsv write from 6th row. Want from first row

Tags: php, csv, export-to-csv, fputcsv

`fputcsv` function write data fro 6th row. But I want to write data from first row.

**what I have tried**

```
// disable caching
$now = gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s");
header("Cache-Control: max-age=0, no-cache, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate");
header("Last-Modified: {$now} GMT");
// force download  
header("Content-Type: application/force-download");
header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
header("Content-Type: application/download");

// disposition / encoding on response body
header("Content-Disposition: attachment;filename={$filename}");
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
$df = fopen("php://output", 'w');
fputcsv($df, array_keys(reset($array)));
foreach ($array as $row) {
      fputcsv($df, $row);
}
fclose($df);
```

what looks like in MS-Excel

[image]

what looks like in Notepad
[image]

Comment: What does the raw CSV look like (i.e. how does it look in a text editor)? What's in rows 1 to 5?

Comment: @SimonMᶜKenzie nothing in 1 to 5th row. I will upload a pic what look like en notepad

Comment: @SimonMᶜKenzie my update question

Comment: Have a look at [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11972864/fputcsv-strange-behaviour).